# Get next value in array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
<?php
$arrFiles = array_diff(scandir("scans", 0), array(".", ".."));
$arrFiles = array_values($arrFiles);
?>
```

that prints fine with this:

```
<?php 
print_r(array_values($arrFiles));
?>
```

and these buttons that I want to use to skip from one image to the prev or next:

```
  <a href="javascript:skipLeft()"><img src="/ico/skip_left.gif" width="12" height="12" hspace="1" vspace="1" />skip left</a> / 
  <a href="javascript:skipRight()"><img src="/ico/skip_right.gif" width="12" height="12" hspace="1" vspace="1" />skip right</a>
```

I probably need some kind of loop, -1 and +1 or prev and next or something.

I've tried so many things. No luck.

Page: http://flamencopeko.net/songs_scans_skip.php

Source: http://flamencopeko.net/songs_scans_skip.txt

Comment: Have you read any php documentation about loops?

Comment: Yes. I have. Tried for() etc.

Comment: So Im not getting what you hope to accomplish with this. What is the end goal?

Comment: Don't you think you should also show us what `skipLeft` and `skipRight` do?

Comment: End goal is to get the skip buttons to change the large image below the thumbs. In alphabetical order.

Comment: I don't have any code for skipLeft() and skipRight() that is close to doing anything.

Comment: You are using PHP inside your JavaScript. Thats not the way it works. Use JavaScript only.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want a loop like this:

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($arrFiles); $i++)
{
  echo "<img src=scans/" . $arrFiles[$i] . ">";
}
```

to select an image using a page by page technique you could use this:

```
if($_GET['p'] >= sizeof($arrFiles)) echo "<img src=scans/" . $arrFiles[sizeof($arrFiles)] . ">";
else{
  echo "<img src=scans/" . $arrFiles[$_GET['p']] . ">";
}
```

use this for links/buttons

```
echo "<a href='yourpagename.php?p=" . $_GET['p']+1 . "'>"; // next
echo "<a href='yourpagename.php?p=" . $_GET['p']-1 . "'>"; // previous
```

you can use the same if as above to filter out max of array size and obviously use 0 as min array size to cover the low end

```
if(!max){ //shownext }
if(!min){ //showprevious }
```

note this is not going to work without proper structuring but you can get the idea

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I tried that now. Nothing happened.

Page: http://flamencopeko.net/songs_scans_skip_2.php

Source: http://flamencopeko.net/songs_scans_skip_2.txt

Comment: modify the path then. (see adjusted edit). The images are there, just not showing. Once you have that, you can then start thinking about how to display them 1 at a time.

Comment: That would certainly not work. Wrong path and quotation. But I see what you mean.

<?php 
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($arrFiles); $i++)
{
  echo "<img src='scans/" . $arrFiles[$i] . "'>";
}
  ?>

works.

Comment: Printed all the A4 scans below each other. Fun! Thanks.

Comment: Like you're saying, I now need to write the actual skip functions.

Comment: Any chance you could help me out with that as well?

Comment: I could but I do not know whether you want to use an inpage technique or a page by page technique (ie load page each time or run a frame within the page)